# how to set kafka-python with kerberos (and how to set JAAS and krb5)

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kerberos

I want to setup kafka consumer (using python) that connects to a remote kafka broker. But it requires a kerberos authentication.

So from what I understood, I am required to have jaas.conf and krb5.conf

the following is my code snippet

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=brokers, group_id='group_id', auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                         security_protocol='SASL_PLAINTEXT', sasl_mechanism='GSSAPI', sasl_kerberos_service_name='kafka')
```

but i am not sure how and where to put the jaas and krb5

I read that i need to set them as

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/kafka/kafka_server_jaas.conf
-Djava.security.krb5.conf=/etc/kafka/krb5.conf
```

but if my understanding is correct, that is for the kafka server (not as client consumer)
if i do indeed need to set both jaas and krb5, how should i do it as a consumer?

because I am not familiar with kerberos, it seems that I am taking bits of information from everywhere an reached to the wrong conclusion. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You might have better luck asking in the Github issues for that library